# Confusion matrix output missing some labels for multi-label classification

Tags: matplotlib, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I have difficulty in creating a classification matrix for multi-label classification to evaluate the performance of the MLPClassifier model. The confusion matrix output should be 10x10 but instead I get 8x8 as it doesn't shows label values for 9 and 10. The class labels of true and predicted labels are from 1 to 10 (unordered). The implementation of the code looks like this:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    side_bar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, linewidth=.5, linecolor="r", fmt=".0f", ax = ax)
    ax.set_xticklabels(side_bar)
    ax.set_yticklabels(side_bar)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.show()
```

[confusion matrix heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRKmz.png)

Edit: The code & output of the constructed confusion matrix are as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
str(cm)

   [[20  0  0  1  0  5  1  0]
   [ 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
   [ 1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0]
   [ 3  0  0  0  0  3  1  1]
   [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
   [ 3  0  0  1  0  2  1  1]
   [ 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  2]
   [ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]]

  '[[20  0  0  1  0  5  1  0]\n [ 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]\n [ 1  1  0  1  0  
   1  0  0]\n [ 3  0  0  0  0  3  1  1]\n [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]\n [ 3  0  
   0  1  0  2  1  1]\n [ 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  2]\n [ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  
   1]]'
```

Could anyone provide me a solution on how can I fix this issue?

Comment: If your array `cm` is 8x8, a 8x8 heatmap will be created.  You might want to add some dummy data to create a reproducible example.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, the confusion matrix array cm should be 10x10, but the cm output is showing 8x8. You might want to have a look at the confusion matrix heatmap to get an idea. How can I add dummy data?

Comment: Well, your confusion matrix array clearly isn't 10x10.  How did you calculate it?  You could add a dummy 10x10 confusion matrix as `cm = np.random.rand(10,10)`, but that will show a 10x10 heatmap.  You also could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67691498/edit) your post and add the output of `str(cm)` to show people how your matrix looks like.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the code & output of the constructed confusion matrix.

Comment: I checked and you are right about both y_pred & y_test containing 8 different values.

Comment: You could use `side_bar = np.unique(y_test)` to get the correct labels.

Comment: I just did but still getting only 8 labels instead of 10.

Comment: If your input only contains 8 labels, why do you want your output to contain 10?

Comment: Because I want to compute confusion matrix output for 10 labels and the input doesn't contain 8 labels. Also, I want to predict the accuracy of 10 labels. The output is a categorical variable and the input is a numerical variable.